# Google Apps Script: Is it possible to log the use of the close button on a Modal Dialogue?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm working on a spreadsheet which opens a modal dialogue when a script begins to execute.  Inside it plays a google-style "working" animation made with CSS:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTmKR.gif]

If I could remove the close button so that the user has to sit at this dialogue box until the script finishes, I would.  I don't want the user to be able to edit the spreadsheet while the script runs, but my understanding is that I can't remove it.

**So, is it instead possible to register when the user clicks the close button so that I can cancel execution of the script?**

---

### This is the code that generates the Modal Dialogue:

#### Code.gs

```
function createpage()
{

var output=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page').evaluate();
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, 'Generating... please wait');

}

function getContent(filename) {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).getRawContent();
}
```

#### Page.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= getContent("CSS") ?>
  </head>
  <body>

<h1>

</h1>

<p>To cancel, click the close button.</p>

<div class="google-loader">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

There is also a `CSS.HTML` file that is pulled into `Page.HTML` by `<?!= getContent("CSS") ?>`.

Comment: Can you post some code snippets?

Comment: I've added the code that generates the modal dialogue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible  to log the click of the built-in close button in a Google Apps Script custom dialog.

The alternative is to add a custom button in your custom dialog that does what you are looking for before closing the dialog by using `google.script.host.close()`.